# How widespread is Bio-neural circuitry?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

The starship Voyager is equipped with experimental 'organic' circuitry, which supposedly "organizes information more efficiently, speeds up response time"- is this circuitry used in ships later assembled? Were any older Federation starships modified so that bio-neural circuitry replaced the more traditional kind?

Comment: According to Memory Alpha the Enterprise E uses bio neural circuitry so chances are that all Sovereign class ships do. My guess is that any new classes of ship built at the same time or after the Intrepid class will use bio neural circuitry

Comment: Honestly the idea that the way to speed up response time is to replace electronics or optronics or whatever they have with something biological is one of the stupidest ideas on Voyager.   And that's saying a lot!

Comment: *In 2152, the starship Enterprise encountered a ship from the future which ran on organic circuitry, a possible descendant of bio-neural circuitry. (ENT: "Future Tense")* - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bio-neural_circuitry

Comment: *In The Q Continuum trilogy, it was revealed that the USS Enterprise-E also possessed the gel packs. During the story, Reginald Barclay discovered that the gel packs were capable of absorbing the psionic energy of the galactic barrier, prompting him to suggest that the crew channel the resulting energy into the Enterprise's shields so that they could increase the time that they could remain in the barrier when attempting to hide from the Calamarain.* - https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bio-neural_gel_pack